# Add data frames row wise with [d]plyr

Tags: r, plyr, dplyr

I have two data frames

```
df1
#    a  b
# 1 10 20
# 2 11 21
# 3 12 22
# 4 13 23
# 5 14 24
# 6 15 25

df2
#   a b
# 1 4 8
```

I want the following output:

```
df3
#    a  b
# 1 14 28
# 2 15 29
# 3 16 30
# 4 17 31
# 5 18 32
# 6 19 33
```

i.e. add df2 to each row of df1.

Is there a way to get the desired output using plyr (mdplyr??) or dplyr?

Answer (score 7):

I see no reason for "dplyr" for something like this. In base R you could just do:

```
df1 + unclass(df2)
#    a  b
# 1 14 28
# 2 15 29
# 3 16 30
# 4 17 31
# 5 18 32
# 6 19 33
```

Which is the same as `df1 + list(4, 8)`.

Comment: @jazzurro, Actually, I like my "alternatively" approach better than my original one.

Comment: Haha. I agree! I could not expect `unclass()` here. I wish I can vote one more time. :)

Comment: Actually--dropping the `mapply` approach because it doesn't scale well.

Comment: I see. I will write down this code in my notebook. :)

Answer (score 4):

One liner with dplyr.

```
mutate_each(df1, funs(.+ df2$.), a:b)

#   a  b
#1 14 28
#2 15 29
#3 16 30
#4 17 31
#5 18 32
#6 19 33
```

Comment: Only `mutate_each(df1, funs(. + df2$.))` would work. No need to specify `a:b` here

Answer (score 2):

A base `R` solution using sweet function `sweep`:

```
sweep(df1, 2, unlist(df2), '+')
#   a  b
#1 14 28
#2 15 29
#3 16 30
#4 17 31
#5 18 32
#6 19 33
```

Comment: I had posted an `mapply` option that was somewhat similar. This performs better than the `mapply` version, but not nearly as well as `unclass`. +1 for the alternative :-)